# Проверить наличие таблицы в БД и если она не существует создать. JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Необходимо создать таблицу в БД с определенными полями только в случае если ее в БД нет.
Запрос вида

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS param1
```

не подойдет, т.к. нужно создать таблицу с конкретными полями типа string, int, string

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался. код запроса для jdbc будет следующий:

```
statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(name varchar(100), id integer primary key auto_increment, nickname varchar(100));");
```